# list content of globalplatform smartcard with APDU

Tags: smartcard, apdu, globalplatform

I'm trying to list GlobalPlatform 2.1.1 compatible smartcard contents, in particular, list installed applets (besides ISD) and/or public keys using APDU commands, but I could not find any example to do that.

Any ref/doc will be apreciated.

ATR: 3B7F94000080318065B0850300EF120FFF829000

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro) or [GPShell](https://sourceforge.net/p/globalplatform/wiki/GPShell/) for some working examples.

Basically you need to authenticate to the ISD (which means that you have to possess the correct keys) and issue `GET STATUS` command (see Global Platform Card Specification 2.1.1, chapter 9.4).

To get information about loaded ISD keys, use `GET DATA` with appropriate tags (chapter 9.3).

Good luck with your project!

EDIT>

Some cards (not many) support ISO 7816-4 `SELECT` APDU with object enumeration and allow iterating over card applications using the following (no authentication is needed):

- `00 A4 04 00 00` -- Select by [truncated] empty application identifier, first or only occurrance
- while SW != `6A 82`

  - `00 A4 04 02 00` -- Get next occurrance

See [ISO 7816-4](http://www.ttfn.net/techno/smartcards/iso7816_4.html#ss6_11_3) for details

EDIT2>

If card uses the default `40..4F` keys, use GlobalPlatformPro (see [here](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro#list--install--delete-applets)):

> java -jar gp.jar -list

**Beware that authentication attempts with wrong keys will almost certainly brick your card** -- see [here](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro#warning-about-correct-keying).

EDIT3>

For Gemalto card with the 'well-known mother key':

> java -jar gp.jar -visa2 -key 47454D5850524553534F53414D504C45 -list

**Beware that authentication attempts with wrong keys will almost certainly brick your card**

Comment: `00 A4 04 00 00` and `00 A4 00 02 00` always output same result:   `Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
6F 65 84 08 A0 00 00 00 18 43 4D 00 A5 59 73 4A
06 07 2A 86 48 86 FC 6B 01 60 0C 06 0A 2A 86 48
86 FC 6B 02 02 01 01 63 09 06 07 2A 86 48 86 FC
6B 03 64 0B 06 09 2A 86 48 86 FC 6B 04 01 05 65
0B 06 09 2B 85 10 86 48 64 02 01 03 66 0C 06 0A
2B 06 01 04 01 2A 02 6E 01 02 9F 6E 06 12 91 21
72 03 00 9F 65 01 FF`  
I already tried GPP (jar) with that creepy warning but seems that those are not the correct keys. Maybe should contact issuer.

Sorry for the format, seems linebreak don't work?

Comment: @Gabriel Since your card is probably Gemalto -- it might be worth trying default Gemalto key -- see edited answer. But please do check with your supplier first -- or you will lock your card.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the application list *without* authenticating, there is a *slight* chance that the following might work:

1. From a card reset, send the APDU `00A40400` to hopefully select the ISD.
2. Then send the APDU `80CA 2F00`.

That last command comes from page 152 of the [GlobalPlatform v2.2.1 specification](https://globalplatform.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/GPC_Specification-2.2.1.pdf#page=152). I've only seen it work on one card: the [Tesla Model 3 NFC Card](https://gist.github.com/darconeous/2cd2de11148e3a75685940158bddf933#applet-list).

If it works, you will get a bunch of concatenated ASN.1 items tagged `61` that contain the AIDs (tag `4F`).

Answer (score 0):

Smart cards were never designed for a dump but for a very fine-granular access like: this file can only be read after PIN verification for writing a challenge-response test with key 9 is necessary. This is the conceptual difference to memory cards like SLE4428 and it means, that you will typically not be able to read everything.

For a javacard, which has no file system, but applets, all of which provide their set of commands the idea of a dump is completely strange, since each applet consists of an arbitrary combination of executable code and persistent variables. What result do you imagine?

ISO 7816-15 defines a public interface to retrieve some information e.g. a list of installed applications, but you can't rely on support of it.

Comment: I'm not thinking in something like "ls -a", but something like <apdu+params for listing issuer javacard applet ID>, in order to select it and operates with it. It seems that I need to authenticate with ISD to access to certain content in card. I know that I must use SCP01 protocol. I'm still researching.